# How to animate the "textColorHint" property of an EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-animation

I want to animate the color of the hint in my edit text, but the following doesn't seem to work.

```
fun animateHintTextColorChange(et: EditText, colorFromResId: Int, colorToResId: Int) {
        val colorFrom = ContextCompat.getColor(et.context, colorFromResId)
        val colorTo = ContextCompat.getColor(et.context, colorToResId)
        val animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(et, "textColorHint", colorFrom, Color.RED)
        animator.setEvaluator(ArgbEvaluator())
        animator.start()
    }
```

Comment: You need to use `PropertyAnimator` or hook animator listener and set animated value using `et.setHintTextColor(animator.getAnimatedValue());`

Comment: Did you try the below does it satisfy your need?

Comment: Sorry @Raghunandan I did not try that, the solution I came up with is much simpler I feel. Thanks though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution thanks to @Nikola Despotoski's hint.

```
fun animateHintTextColorChange(editText: EditText, colorFrom: Int, colorTo: Int, startDelay: Long = 0) : Animator {
        val animator = ValueAnimator.ofObject(ArgbEvaluator(), colorFrom, colorTo)
        animator.duration = DURATION_MEDIUM
        animator.startDelay = startDelay
        animator.addUpdateListener { animator -> editText.setHintTextColor(animator.animatedValue as Int) }

        return animator
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a CustomSpan

```
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.text.style.CharacterStyle;
import android.text.style.UpdateAppearance;


public class CustomSpan extends CharacterStyle implements UpdateAppearance {

    private int color;

    public int getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(int color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public CustomSpan() {

    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint paint) {
        paint.setColor(color);

    }
}
```

Then use ObjectAnimator

```
    final EditText editText = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

    CustomSpan span = new CustomSpan();

    final String text = getResources().getString(R.string.edit_hint);

    final SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(text);

    int start = 0;
    int end = text.length();
    spannableString.setSpan(span, start, end, 0);



    int colorFrom = Color.BLACK;
    int colorTo = Color.RED;
    int duration = 2000;

    final ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(
            span, CHANGE_COLOR_PROPERTY,  colorFrom, colorTo);

    objectAnimator.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
    objectAnimator.setDuration(duration);
    objectAnimator.start();

    objectAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
           editText.setHint(spannableString);
        }
    });
```

The CustomProperty

```
private static final Property<CustomSpan, Integer> CHANGE_COLOR_PROPERTY
        = new Property<CustomSpan, Integer>(Integer.class, "CHANGE_COLOR_PROPERTY") {

    @Override
    public void set(CustomSpan span, Integer value) {
        span.setColor(value);
    }
    @Override
    public Integer get(CustomSpan object) {
        return object.getColor();
    }
};
```

Note : If your duration is slow you can see some intermediary colors that start from start color to end color.

Update : I would also suggest to look at MutableForegroundSpan @ http://flavienlaurent.com/blog/2014/01/31/spans/